# What does fixed regressor say about our linearity condition?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, regression

The linearity condition states that $y_i=(\vec{x}_i)^{T}\vec{\beta}$ for all $i$. Now, if we have fixed regressors, $\{\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2,\cdots\}$, our linearity condition only says for those $\vec{x}_i$, there is a linear relationship. So it does not assume linearity when we have some $\vec{x}_j$ that is not in the set of fixed regressors.

However, if the regressors are random as well, the linearity condition says for all $\vec{x}$ there are, linearity holds. Therefore, if we have an experimental design and had fixed regressors, we can only infer $\vec{x}$ that has happened in the fixed regressor during the experiment and cannot infer otherwise. However, with stochastic regressors, we can infer any $\vec{x}$. Is that right?

Comment: Are the  $x_i´s$ not  always fix ? If you have a sample then $x_i$ has a specific value.

Comment: There is a difference between randomly draw x like in a survey and determining the x you want in an experiment